# How can I specify transcendental numbers for specific spacing in LaTeX (say for instance the dot separation in a Table of Contents)?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like to add one fun math concept to my dissertation (formatting as that is how much freedom there is) and I figured the best way is to incorporate `pi` as dot spacing.  However, when I tried to add:

```
\newcommand{\pi}{3.14159265358979}
```

as a dot separation number, the PDF didn't compile correctly.  When I instead used the golden ratio:

```
\newcommand{\goldenRatio}{1.618033988749895}
```

this does work.

```
% Dot separation definition
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\goldenRatio}
```

Any ideas on what the mathematical limits are with TeX?

Comment: This has nothing to do with mathematical limits but with the fact that the macro `\pi` is already defined and prints a Greek pi in math mode. You must have received an error `Command \pi already defined.` Don't ignore errors.

Comment: You're using neither pi or the golden ratio, but only approximations thereof. This should already tell you that the problem is elsewhere and not in the fact that pi is transcendental.

Comment: Thank you to both of you!  I didn't have ```\pi``` as a symbol in my dissertation so I thought it would be alright.  Turns out that was incorrect.  Simply adding ```\piValue``` worked.  And I wanted to be as clever as possible without writing an infinite series as a specific length dimension.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I type

```
\newcommand{\pi}{3.14159265358979}
```

somewhere in *any* LaTeX file I get the following

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \pi already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

because `\pi` is a macro defined in the LaTeX kernel (and in plain TeX) expanding to `\mathchar"119`, whose job is to print a `π` in math mode. *Never* ignore errors: whatever PDF output comes after that is just the result of TeX trying to recover but is usually garbage.

If you want to use that *number* you should create a macro with a different name, like e.g.

```
\newcommand{\pivalue}{3.14159265358979}
```

---

As you address mathematical limits in TeX, let me add that even if this issue had nothing to do with them, there *are* some. TeX uses integer arithmetic, and all its lengths are multiples of its internal length unit, the so-called scaled point (roughly 5nm). Adding lots of decimal does not really help because they will be eventually truncated:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ttfamily
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{#1pt & \global\dimen0=#1pt \the\dimen0 & \number\dimen0sp\\}
\begin{tabular}{ll@{ = }r}
What you input: & \multicolumn{2}{l}{What TeX understands:}\\
\hline
\foo{3.14}
\foo{3.141}
\foo{3.1415}
\foo{3.14159}
\foo{3.141592}
\foo{3.1415926}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 :-)..........

Comment: This is beautiful!  Since I'm using Ubuntu to compile my document I never saw the error message about redefining ```pi``` and wasn't worried about it because the symbol never made an appearance in my document.

Comment: @ChristopherCreveling The fact that you see no error is very strange. I don't see what Ubuntu should do different than any other distribution. Do you run `(pdf)latex` from bash or through some editor like TeXStudio?

Comment: @campa if you install the default packages in Ubuntu you get a menu entry for an editor with a compile button, so it's the default way of doing it.  I can't remember which editor as I install TeX Live directly, not the outdated version Ubuntu offers in LTS releases

Comment: You know what, I actually found that exact error message that you mentioned earlier ```! LaTeX Error: Command \pi already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.```  I'm running a makefile through bash.

Comment: @ChrisH Oh, thanks for the info. I run everything from bash on Suse so that's how far my knowledge goes...

Comment: @campa I use the terminal as well, not just for LaTeX but also Python etc., and then get frustrated when my students ignore my instructions to do the same and miss most of the output!